# How can call through browser on PC if I have a SIP-account?

Tags: javascript, websocket, sip

I have a SIP account from my internet provider and I can call to a phone using different SIP clients. 
Also I have some kind of web application for personal use. I need to call through browser in it. I know that I can do it using websockets, but my provider doesn't have websocket server for sip clients.

So, where should I start? How can make sip over websocket and websocket over sip connections possible?

Comment: Do you have to call through browser or do you just have to initiate call with the browser (integrate external softphone with the browser)?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that something has changed in the last 2 years... There are some websocket2sip proxy applications and there are some javascript SIP clients too. The problem is that they are mostly abandoned. VOIP and the related tech is fairly reliable and standard. The amount of open source and free and easily scalped software attracts it's own deplorables. As a result the quality code and intellectual property has been consolidated into commercial entities. On the one hand they are expensive and on the other you may never get there in terms of sweat equity because it takes a lot to make commercial grade software. (try twillo)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way using web sockets if the server does not have this functionality. Otherwise, a browser based SIP client is possible with sipml5 (http://sipml5.org) for example.